# Cleaner way to write this Javascript function

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, function, coding-style

Looking for a better/cleaner/simpler way to write this:

```
const line1 = 'a string';
const line2 = 'a second string';
const line3 = 'a third string';

  const howManyLinesToRender = (line) => {
   if (line === 1) return [line1];
   if (line === 2) return [line1, line2];
   if (line === 3) return [line1, line2, line3];
```

Comment: The whole function body can be replaced with `return [line1, line2, line3].slice(0, line)`

Comment: I think you need to define what you mean by clean code or rephrase your Question to something like "Is there another way to do this?". Perhaps not everyone agree on what clean code means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler way would be to use switch:

```
const howManyLinesToRender = (line) => {
   switch (line) {
    case 1: return [line1]
    case 2: return [line1, line2];
    case 3: return [line1, line2, line3];
  }
}
```

but as CRice notes in the comments of your question, this very example is satisfiable  also by:

```
return [line1, line2, line3].slice(0, line)
```

that is a cleaner oneliner.

Answer (score 2):

You can use slice() method. The slice() method returns the selected elements in an array, as a new array object.

The slice() method selects the elements starting at the given start argument, and ends at, but does not include, the given end argument.

```
var arr=[line1, line2, line3];
return arr.slice(0, line);
```

or

```
return [line1, line2, line3].slice(0,line);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use switch statement

```
const howManyLinesToRender = (line) => {
    switch (line) {
        case 1: return [line1]
        case 2: return [line1, line2];
        case 3: return [line1, line2, line3];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is that better?